# Issue with recursive function arguments

Tags: c++, function

I'm writing a simple recursive function, but I'm having issues calling it because of the arguments types. I'm new to C++ and typed languages, so it may be a really simple fix I don't understand.

The error:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'find(char*&, char* [4], const unsigned int&)'
    find(charset, word, length);
                              ^
```

The function definition:

```cpp
void find(char * charset, char * word, const unsigned int len_) {};
```

The function call:

```cpp
const unsigned int length = 4;
char * charset = genCharset(33, 94);
char * word[length];
find(charset, word, length);
```

Hope someone can point out the problem and provide an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char * word[length];` is an array of `char *` aka:

```
[char* 1, char * 2, char* 3, ...]
```

Your function is expecting just a `char*`. Since it seems you are expecting a character set, you probably just want `char charset[4]`, or better yet `std::vector<char>` or `std::array<char>`.

Comment: Why would vector<char> be better than char array? Most of the type it is to use it as a buffer, so array will have better performance.

Comment: @AntoninGAVREL, sure, then use `std::array`, don't use char buffers